# using memcached under bluemix with php

Tags: php, memcached, ibm-cloud

I am trying to build a php application using memcached on the Bluemix cloud.
When adding the memcached service I get the server name, port, username and password. I installed memcached on my local server to test my application and it works:

```
$memcache = new Memcached();
$memcache->addServer('Server', port) or die ("Could not connect");

$version = $memcache->getVersion();
echo "Server's version: ".$version."<br/>\n";

$memcache->set('val', 99);
echo $memcache->get('val');
```

But when I run it on Bluemix it returns the version as: `255.255.255` and doesn't read back values I store.
There is username and password which I tried to add using:

```
$memcache->setSaslAuthData('user', 'pass');
```

But when I run this it, the page simply stops loading on that line.

I am new to memcached so any ideas and help will be appritiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only mention of Memcached I can fin on Bluemix is a 3rd party service provided by RedisLabs.

On the [HowTo Connect](https://redislabs.com/memcached-howto#opening-a-connection-to-memcached-using-pecl-memcached) page, it mentions a couple of additional calls that are required:

```
$memcache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL, true);
// addServer
// setSaslAuthData - that is also in your code
```

So, it appears that the RedisLabs may also require the use of the Memcache binary protocol as well.

Comment: Redis Labs worker bee here - yep, I can verify that we do, in fact, require the use of SASL/binary protocol because of security considerations when Memcached Cloud is used via a PaaS provider.

Comment: You are right.  I had to install the SASL enabled memcached variance but you definetly helped me solve it! thank you.